# How to cast a field in Elasticsearch pipelines / Painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, casting

I have an application which is logging `level` as integers. I am using filebeat to send the logs to ES. I have set `level` as string in the ES index, which is working for most of the applications. But when filebeat is receiving an integer, the indexation is failing of course with:

```
"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"field [level] of type [java.lang.Integer] cannot be cast to [java.lang.String]"
```

In my document: `"level":30`

I added a step Script in my ingestion pipeline. But I can't manage to make it work: either I get a compilation error or the script is somehow failing and nothing at all get indexed.

Some very basic script I tried:

```
if (doc['level'].value == 30) {
    doc['level'].value = 'info';
}
```

Any idea on how to handle this in ES pipelines?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to transform data before sending to ES.

You can usse processsor in filebeat to filter you data.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/defining-processors.html

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've done actually. So I was getting the error on a step before the step I was mentioning in the thread.